# How to group records based on registered time considering entries in another table for the reporting month?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, date-arithmetic, lateral-join

I have a table A with registered time associated for an account , there can be only one entry for each id.

For all the Id's present in Table A there will be entries in Table B like below with state

[image]

**Expected transformed table**

For each ID in table A If there is **NO** corresponding entry for an ID is present in table B for the registered time's month - want to classify it as New for that reporting month. Likewise if there are no corresponding entries in subsequent months in table B for an ID would like to classify them as well as New.

Eg:

**ID 111** ~ Registered in November 2020 => Table B has no entries for ID 111 => Transformed table has an entry for ID 111 for the november month with state New.
**ID 112** ~ Registered in November 2020 => Table B has entries for ID 112 in the month of November => Transformed table has no entry for ID 112
**ID 113** ~ Registered in November 2020 => Table B has entries for ID 113 starting December  => Transformed table has an entry for ID 113 for the november month with state New.
**ID 114** ~ Registered in November 2020 => Table B has entries for ID 114 starting Feb 2021 => Transformed table has an entry for ID 114 for the months of november,December,Jan month with state New.

[image]

Comment: Your results are not totally consistent with your explanation: presumably, there should be only one row for id `113`, for the month of november.

Comment: you'r right for 113 there should be only one entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am following this correctly, you can use `generate_series()` and a lateral join:

```
select a.id, 'new' state, s.dt
from tablea a
cross join lateral (
    select generate_series(
        date_trunc('month', a.registered_time), 
        coalesce(
            date_trunc('month', min(b.time)) - interval '1 month', 
            date_trunc('month', a.registered_time)
        ),
        '1 month'
    )
    from tableb b
    where b.id = a.id
) s(dt)
```

The trick lies in the generation of the argument to `generate_series()`: if there is at least one entry available in `b`, we generate the date series from the beginning of the month of the registered time of `a` until the prior month to the earliest date in `b`; in case there is a date in `b` in the same month as in `a`, this generates an empty range, and the original row is filtered out. Else, we fall back on the registered time as end of range (which generates a range made of a single date).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=dc8f3c34be82c7ca80929215a10e9d89)**:

```
 id | state | dt                 
--: | :---- | :------------------
111 | new   | 2020-11-01 00:00:00
113 | new   | 2020-11-01 00:00:00
114 | new   | 2020-11-01 00:00:00
114 | new   | 2020-12-01 00:00:00
114 | new   | 2021-01-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: @Mozhi: Snowflake and Postgres are two different databases, this solution will not work in Snowflake. Changing the database tag on the question basically invalidates the answer.